# ASP.NET MVC - browser keeps remembering inputs for different models

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two models that go like that:

```
public class Register 
{
    public string Login {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
}

public class Login
{
   public string LoginField {get;set;}
   public string PasswordField {get;set;}
}
```

Now, on my every page i have login box, and when i go to a register page, my browser is autocompleting fields from login box, and it is putting the same data into a register form! Why is that? Why is browser caching info for fields with different IDs?

Answer (score 5):

> Why is that? Why is browser caching info for fields with different IDs?

I guess it's by design. You could turn autocomplete off by adding the `autocomplete` attribute to the input fields that you don't want to be auto completed:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

Comment: Yeah, i know about autocomplete, but i also want to know how does browser recognize fields that inputs are cached - because i have 2 completely different input fields and it is caching data for both of them. O.o

Comment: Look at your browser settings. You probably turned on this feature. Once you turn it on, the browser will remember values you have entered in input fields for a given domain and automatically prefill them when you visit this domain.

Comment: But why does it remember same data for different inputs?

Comment: Because you probably used the same names for your inputs within your application.

Comment: Well, thats the case! IDs and names are different!